# Raise TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection time out while sockt.send_all(request)

Tags: sockets, concurrency, timeout

client socket settings:

```
 s = socket.create_connection(self._addr, timeout=15)
 s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_KEEPALIVE, 1)
 s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
 s.settimeout(300)
```

server socket settings:

```
 sock = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET)
 sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
 sock.setblocking(False)
 sock.bind(addr)
 sock.listen(512)
```

about 300 clients for each client machine( 8 core CPU).
about 300 clients  for each server worker serving. 
the requst body is small maybe 2KB.
somtetimes the client will raise timeout error while s.send_all(request) far less than the 300s, especially when the clients is intensively requesting.

I don't known where is the problem? in the client side or server side?

Answer (score 0):

Finanly i found the reason is not about concurrency. it caused by LB and keep-alive options. 
  
While the server sends a FIN, LB will delete the connection info after 2 minutes, regardless of whether the client sends a FIN.
 
 The client didn't sends FIN to the server, and after tcpkeepalivetime, the client will begin send detecor message, but LB dont recognize because the connection info has removed. so client will retry tcpkeepaliveprobes times, then send a RST.
 
After this, if the client send somothing, the TimeoutError raised. 
 
In my application the server does not send message actively. 
 
My solution for this situation is: before the client send, check the socket is readable, if the socket is readable, the connect is not normal, need close the socket and re-connect withe the server.

(forgive my poor english, i hope this maybe help someone)